# Is there a long polling framework in PHP/Apache analagous to Tornado?

Tags: php, python, comet, tornado, long-polling

Is there something like the Tornado framework written in PHP or any examples of how to tie it (Tornado or another reliable framework) in to a site already built on PHP/MYSQL/Apache?

Answer (score 1):

at eyeOS we have developed our entire long polling stack using php/mysql/apache.

We use mysql memory tables for message exchanging, and some tricks at php level.

eyeOS is open source so you can view/modify/reuse the code under the terms of the AGPL3 license.

The code is here:

https://code.eyeos.org/trunk/eyeos/system/Frameworks/NetSync/

And the js part:

https://code.eyeos.org/trunk/eyeos/extern/js/eyeos/netSync/

It is giving really good results in our demo server with hundreds of concurrent users.

However, this is a lightweight implementation, not sure if it will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!....what are the issues with scaling up to more users?...just hardware or what you have built/used just fundamentally doesn't worry about scale?

Comment: We have developed it from scatch, with scalability in mind... However, our demo server never have more than 1.000 concurrent users, so I can not promise anything that exceeds this number. However, if you are planning to use it in a high traffic site, you should consider two options, or fine tune apache, or use lighttpd for the long polling part, in a different port.